# JAVA Synchronisation

Tags: java

I have a master program, and a client program. Whats the best way in Java to connect these two programs so they are synchronized, where if one change on one program happens then the change happens on the other?. The programs are identical but the GUI is different one for a mobile device and the other for a computer.

I have tried looking on the internet but have just been baffled. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have two programs that share pretty much the whole code, except the gui. You could extract that code into a library and use the library in both. But please make your question more clear

Comment: ok great, so when one change happens it will be happen on the other? will the library need to be updated via a network? because they would be the programs would be run in two separate locations.

Answer (score 0):

Make a server with some web services. Then all your programs will be communicating with the server. You don't have to write something twice - you just change the UI layer and than you can it easily run it everywhere.

You solution has a big flaw - if you liked to add one more device (other mobile platform), the coding would be enormous and too difficult.